# Nuget SignalR installs jQuery 1.6.4

Tags: nuget, signalr, nuget-package

I use Install-Package on the package manager command line to type:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

I have jQuery 1.7.4 but Nuget installs 1.6.4

I am trying to use Nuget Uninstall-Package command to get rid of the jQuery 1.6.4

PM> Uninstall-Package jQuery 1.6.4
Uninstall-Package : No compatible project(s) found in the active solution.

Shall I just delete the javascripts 1.6.4, but the nuget is adding stuff to packages.config
and the packages folder in the solution which is part of source control

Comment: Did you install jQuery 1.7.4 into your project via NuGet or just manually copy the files from somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete it, or don't use it in your code, it should be ok since jQuery 1.7.4 should be supported

From [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#clientsetup)

> A JavaScript client requires references to jQuery and the SignalR core
>   JavaScript file. The jQuery version must be 1.6.4 or major later
>   versions, such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1.

Comment: I had to use the -Force command in Nuget Package Manager Console, because SignalR specified it as a dependancy.  The thing is the codebase has 1.5 and 1.7, so perhaps the SignalR installer just checks if there is a jQuery under 1.6.4 and if it sees one it installs 1.6.4, then it all went into TFS find and built, whew!...........                                                                                                                               Uninstall-Package jQuery -Version 1.6.4 -Force